# Need help explaining why a matrix product AB will have linearly dependent columns if the columns of B itself is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

This is what i have reasoned so far:

If the columns of B are linearly dependent, then the equation $Bx=0$ has at least 1 non-zero solution.

(1) $Bx= x_1 b_1 + 0 b_2 + ... + 0 b_p = x_1 b_1 = 0$

This implies $b_1$ is a zero vector. If we left multiply $Bx$ by a matrix $A$, such that the product $AB$ is defined, we get:

(2) $A(Bx)= A(x_1 b_1) = x_1 (Ab_1) = (AB)x = 0$

Since $(AB)x=0$ Then the equation has a non zero solution which in turn makes the columns of $(AB)$ linearly dependent.

Is this reasoning correct? Did i just show that if the columns of B are linearly dependent then the columns of AB are also linearly dependent?

Comment: Your idea is right. You can also think as $AB$ beeing the composition of two linear mappings represented by the matrices $A$ and $B$. $B$ has linear depend columns, so $B$ has a non trivial kernel, this means you have a vector $x\neq 0$ s.t $Bx=0$ and therefore $ABx = A0 = 0$, which shows that the kernel of $AB$ is also non trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is completely correct! To formalize this: we can say the following:

Since the columns of $B$ are linearly dependent, then there exists a vector $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $B\vec{x}=0$. Then:

$$(AB)\vec{x}=A(B\vec{x})=A\cdot \vec{0} = 0$$
Thus, the columns of $AB$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be of size $n \times p$ and $B$ be of size $ p \times n $

Since the columns of $B$ are linearly dependent, then there exists constants $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ not all zero, such that

$ c_1 b_1 + c_2 b_2 + ... + c_n b_n = 0 \hspace{36pt}(1) $

Pre-multiplying this vector equation by the matrix $A$, we get,

$ c_1 A b_1 + c_2 A b_2 + ... + c_n A b_n = 0 \hspace{36pt} (2)$

Now, the matrix $A B = [ A b_1, A b_2, ..., A b_n ] \hspace{36pt} (3)$

So equation $(2)$ implies that the columns of $AB$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: How do we know that step 2 is true and wouldn't produce an inconsistent solution?